# measuring performance - using real clicks vs "ab" command

Tags: mysql, django

I have a web site in closed beta, developed in Django, runs with Mysql on Debian.

In the last few days, the main page has been showing a slowdown. For every ten clicks, one or two receives extremely slow response (10 secs or more), others are as fast as they used to be.

When I was searching for the problem, I ran into this issue that I couldn't grasp:

`top` command shows that when I request the main page, mysql shoots up to 90% - 100% cpu usage. I get the page just as the cpu use gets back to normal. So, I thought, it is db.

Then I called `ab` with parameters `-n 1000 -c 5`, I got decent performance, about 100 pages per second, just as it was before the slowdown. I would imagine a worse performance as 10-20% of requests take 10 secs to load.

Is this conflict between `ab` and "real" clicks normal, or am I using ab in a wrong configuration?

Comment: Have you tried MySQL's slow query logging? Did you profile the application?

Comment: No, not yet. Actually I am not asking about the reasons of slowdown (However I may have to, soon), I am just curious about why slowdown is not reflected in ab's output.

Comment: It may be somewhere in code that depends on user being logged in, for example.

Comment: That's a good point. Can I use AB in such a way that it sends requests from an impersonated user?

Answer (score 0):

ab doesn't execute many parts of the page (javascript i.e.) so you'll notice probably a sensible difference in pressure to the webserver.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the slowdown does not stem from the loading or executing javascript (js files are compressed, versioned and have far-future expiration days).

Comment: But does the javascript do some other call to the webserver (i.e. ajax) when executed on the client side?

Comment: No, there's no ajax on the page I am benchmarking. It may be worth to mention that the browser freezes while waiting for the server (for about 10 secs), and then gets and renders the page very fast.

Comment: ok... so the problem must be on other page element not handled by ab, like session data. Do you store your session on mysql?